# Performance of assigning values between Javascript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, performance

What is the upper limit for assigning variables bidirectionally between PHP and Javascript on an average line before I start getting performance issues?

Lets say I have a ridiculous number of variables like 10000 which are mostly string, boolean and float variables which are being updated, created and destroyed. Would the browser and line be able to handle this many vars?

Note: I am talking about a connection between a server and a host-machine at any given place in the world.

Comment: "Assign" as in "send back and forth via separate AJAX requests"? 'Cause there's no such thing as a direct "assignment" of values from Javascript to PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't aggregate them, 10K variables is a lot. If you aggregate them in a bunch of HTTP requests (either via Ajax or to just submit only once to deal with all those variables) it's more than reasonable.